# Module that expands horizontally on click/hover

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm wondering if anyone knows of an extension that can allow a 'sidebar' positioned module to expand to full page width on click or on hover? Or know of anyway to achieve this in Joomla?
Any advice/suggestions/ideas would be most welcome.
Thank you in advance
Donna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a paid extension called EngageBox by Tassos that I use for things like that.  It is fairly customizable so you could take the example from "Side Navigation Menu" and just change the width to be full screen.

http://www.tassos.gr/joomla-extensions/responsive-scroll-triggered-box-for-joomla

Comment: thank you, I've had a quick look and sent the developer a message.